# Multiple query date range

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have multiple queries that I run each day, Is there a way to set a date range for multiple selects rather than enter the date in each select.I use oracle sql developer to run these.

here is an example of just three but there are around a dozen queries:

```
select count(*)"Tall ord"
from cr_ordpar
inner join cr_palhis on cr_palhis.pikref = cr_ordpar.pikref
inner join CR_LODHED_DESP on cr_lodhed_desp.ilodno = cr_ordpar.ILODNO
where cr_palhis.hstdat between '24-nov-15 07:00' and '25-nov-15 07:00:00'
and hststs_str = 'Pallet Output From Racking'
and cr_palhis.palhgt = '2700'
order by cr_lodhed_desp.lodref;

select count(*)"Tall del"
from cr_palhis
where cr_palhis.hstdat between '24-nov-15 07:00' and '25-nov-15 07:00:00'
and hststs_str = 'Pallet Deleted'
and cr_palhis.palhgt = 2700
and cr_palhis.rakblk <> 510; 

select  count(*)"Tall ind"
from cr_palhis
where cr_palhis.hstdat between '24-nov-15 07:00' and '25-nov-15 07:00:00'
and hststs_str = 'Pallet Indexed'
and cr_palhis.PALHGT = '2700';
```

Comment: `'24-nov-15 07:00'` is not a **DATE**, it is a **string**. What is the **data type** of `cr_palhis.hstdat`?

Comment: My Question would be how the end result is manipulated. Is it justa report or we need to pass this to some other Front end tool?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your DATE.

- Firstly, `'24-nov-15 07:00'` is not a **DATE**, it is a **string**. You must always use **TO_DATE** to explicitly convert a literal into DATE. Also, remember **TO_DATE** is NLS dependent if you do not mention the **NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE**. `NOV` is not the same in other  languages.
- `YY` format was long ago recongnised as **Y2K** bug and the world already saw the efforts to get rid off it. Either mention complete `YYYY` or use `RR` format, but understand it before implementing.

```
TO_DATE('24-nov-2015 07:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi','nls_date_language=ENGLISH')
```

You could use **GROUP BY** clause to get the **different counts** in a single query. Given that all the conditions remain same.

```
SELECT hststs_str,
  COUNT(*) cnt
FROM cr_ordpar
INNER JOIN cr_palhis
ON cr_palhis.pikref = cr_ordpar.pikref
INNER JOIN CR_LODHED_DESP
ON cr_lodhed_desp.ilodno = cr_ordpar.ILODNO
WHERE cr_palhis.hstdat 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('24-nov-2015 07:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi','nls_date_language=ENGLISH') 
AND     TO_DATE('25-nov-2015 07:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi','nls_date_language=ENGLISH')
AND hststs_str       IN( 'Pallet Output From Racking', 
                         'Pallet Deleted', 
                         'Pallet Indexed'
                       )
AND cr_palhis.palhgt  = '2700'
AND cr_palhis.rakblk <> 510
GROUP BY hststs_str
ORDER BY cnt;
```